# Call different predicate if variable is not instantiated

Tags: prolog

Having this snippet

```
foo :- getVar(X).
```

How can I do a really simple thing such as: "if the variable X comes out of getVar instatiated, call `bar/1` else call `baz/1`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an *if-then-else* control construct and the `nonvar/1` standard built-in predicate. For example:

```
foo :-
    get_var(X),
    (   nonvar(X) ->
        bar(X)
    ;   baz(X)
    ).
```